# EF Code First migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have some problem with migrations i can't understand. 
For example, I drop column from one of the tables(by this I mean drop field from class, of course, not dropping column from database manually), create new migration and update database. It works just fine. 
But when I run the application, it says that can't drop column that was already dropped after applying migration. 
Then I dropped _MigrationHistory Table and re-enabled migrations. Everything works fine again, while  i'm not deleting one of dbcontext entities and not applying new migration. Update-database gives no errors. But when I run the application I got en error that dbo. can't be deleted because it doesn't exist. Of course it doesn't!
Seems to me like my  migration applyes twice, when I do update-database and when i run my appliration. Is it possible? AutomaticMigrationsEnabled is set to  false. But we turned Automatic Migrations on before in the project. Maybe this is the reason? 
Pleace help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Show exacly error message what you get.

Comment: Cannot drop the table 'dbo.BillingPlan', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: Perhaps the best is not to drop columns in the database.  Perhaps the best is to delete the property in the Model's class and then do the migration (this migration is going to delete this column in the database).

Comment: Maybe i wrote not clear enough(not english speaking, sorry). I do all changes with DbContext classes, i don't change database manually, this is CODE first, i get it.

Comment: I try this and works for me. Show how you enable autmatic migrations. Maybe here is a reason.

Comment: That error indicates you are trying to drop a TABLE not a COLUMN. What database initializer are you using?

Comment: Maybe i wrote not clear enough or you read not too good. There were multiple errors. I wrote only last one of them.  It's similar because after successful adding column through add-migration and update database  i've got an error on run that table already has this column, after deleting it was the same: ok when i perform update-database and error on running the application that i want to delete column that dosn't exist. Same when i dropped the whole entity - ok on apply migration and error on run. Just like it tries to do both automatic and non automatic migrations. Automatic are switched off.

Comment: I enabled automatic migrations by setting  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; in Configuration class constructor

Answer (score 0):

Check the migrations history table in the database. I am working with EF7 and just had this happen to me. It seemed exactly like the migration was running a second time and therefore the very first table listed created an error.
When I manually added the migration entry (migrationID and productversion) it seemed to clear up.

Comment: No, migration history table was exactly how it supposed to be.  I guess, I we got my db and model unsincronised in some moment(most likely when i turned off automatic migrations and started to do it with add-migration/update-database). I renamed db, re-enabled migrations in my project  and recreated db through initial migration. After that I transfered data from renamed db to the new one. We kept working, did new migrations and problem disappeared. But I would rather understood this problem deeper to use more suitable way to solve it, if it's happen again.

Comment: I'm going to try and reproduce this. Should be simple since it has happened to me repeatedly in this project I'm working on. Just curious. are you working with EF 7 or 6?